# drawInRect a transparent PNG image :Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawing, transparent, drawrect

I have a background view with an image which fill all the view. Above this view, I added another view with `backgroundColor` `[UIColor clear]` and the attribute opaque to `NO`.

Here is what I would like to happen:

[image: The desired outcome]

Here is what happens instead:

[image: The current outcome]

I want to draw a png image with transparency above this last view with `drawInRect:`. The problem is that all the transparency of the image is filled with the pixels of the first view (the one with the image).
If I do `addSubview:` the problem is fixed, but I have to to do a draw.

Does anyone have the answer of my problem?

Comment: I do not understand the setup, nor the problem. Maybe an image would help?

Comment: This one is with drawInRect http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/40/beforevy.png/ And this one http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/826/afterf.png/ with addSubview. The last one is correct, but I want the same result but with drawInRect.

Comment: need more clear elaboration..

Comment: My understanding is that the problem is the thin green outline around each card: you would like to see the card that's been drawn before it in that space, rather than the green background, right?

Comment: why don't you remove the green background around the cards? you would get the desired result...

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yeah i would like to see the card that's been drawn before and not the green background. The green outline around each car is normaly transparent, because it's png images.

Comment: @DavidGoncalves I flagged the question for reopening, I think there's a decent chance the moderators will reopen it.

Comment: here is my `drawRect:` method code : - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{    
    [currentImage.image drawInRect:rect];
}